# Unable to View Specific Processes via SNMP in RHEL

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp

I'm attempting to configure SNMP to expose several processes on a Linux (RHEL 7) box for monitoring purposes.  I've added the appropriate `proc` directives to `snmp.conf` and done both a reload and restart for `snmpd` to attempt to get this to work, but the information for those processes isn't visible.

I am not the one who did the base `snmpd` configuration, and I'm not extremely familiar with the "how-to" of `snmpd` configuration, but it appears to me that the `snmpd.conf` is pretty much the default config file, so I suspect I'm missing something simple that I need to add.

Here's a sanitized version of `snmpd.conf`:

```
###############################################################################
#
# snmpd.conf:
#
###############################################################################
#
# Many more configuration directives exist than are mentioned in this file.
# For full details, see the snmpd.conf(5) manual page.
#
# All lines beginning with a '#' are comments and are intended for you
# to read.  All other lines are configuration commands for the agent.

###############################################################################
# Access Control
###############################################################################

# As shipped, the snmpd demon will only respond to queries on the
# system mib group until this file is replaced or modified for
# security purposes.

####
# First, map the community name "changeme" into a "security name"

#       sec.name  source          community
com2sec notConfigUser  default       changeme

####
# Second, map the security name into a group name:

#       groupName      securityModel securityName
group   notConfigGroup v1           notConfigUser
group   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser

####
# Third, create a view for us to let the group have rights to:

# Make at least  snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public system fast again.
#       name           incl/excl     subtree         mask(optional)
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1

####
# Finally, grant the group read-only access to the systemview view.

#       group          context sec.model sec.level prefix read   write  notif
access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none

###############################################################################

###########################################################################
# SECTION: Monitor Various Aspects of the Running Host
#
#   The following check up on various aspects of a host.

# proc: Check for processes that should be running.
#     proc NAME [MAX=0] [MIN=0]
#
#     NAME:  the name of the process to check for.  It must match
#            exactly (ie, http will not find httpd processes).
#     MAX:   the maximum number allowed to be running.  Defaults to 0.
#     MIN:   the minimum number to be running.  Defaults to 0.
#
#   The results are reported in the prTable section of the UCD-SNMP-MIB tree
#   Special Case:  When the min and max numbers are both 0, it assumes
#   you want a max of infinity and a min of 1.

proc  httpd
```

Here's the sanitized output from `snmptable`:

```
[user@host ~]$ snmptable -v1 -Ci -Cb -c changeme localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2
End of MIB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ucdavis: No entries
[user@host ~]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing the following in the `snmpd.conf`:

```
# UCD Process & Disk Tables.
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9
```

Once that was added, the following command yielded the following results:

```
[user@host ~]$ snmptable -v1 -Ci -Cb -c changeme localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2
End of MIB
SNMP table: UCD-SNMP-MIB::prTable

 index Index        Names Min Max Count ErrorFlag                  ErrMessage  ErrFix ErrFixCmd
     1     1        httpd   1   0    10   noError                             noError
[user@host ~]$
```